# Shortcut for all the possible permutation of a set of numbers for m digits

Tags: python-3.x, finite-field, abstract-algebra

I have been working on finite field. Suppose I have a prime number `p=7`. So I get  a list `q=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Now I want all the possible **permutation** of the elements of set q for 7 places. For example [1,1,1,4,6,3,1] is one of the possible permutation. Is there any inbuilt command in python for doing that? Actually I am working with bigger field where P is `127 (p=127).`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `permutation of the elements of set q for 7 places`? `[1,1,1,4,6,3,1] ` is not a permutation of `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: the problem is that with 127 numbers you have 127**127 cases. Just not possible to process in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't permutations because elements are repeated, this looks more like a product.

you can use `itertools.product` on repeated `q` lists (here for 3 elements):

```
import itertools

q=[0,1,2]   # or q = list(range(3))

for z in itertools.product(*(q,)*len(q)):  # using arg unpacking like if it was (q,q,q)
    z = list(z) # to convert as list
    print(z)
```

prints:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
...snip...
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

for `p=3` it prints `3**3 = 27` values. If `p=127` well... sounds not reasonable.

Comment: I need those tuples in the form of a list, like [0,0,2] instead of (0,0,2).

Comment: you _can_ access elements in a tuple (reading) exactly like a list. better now?